# How can mysql_connect function be supported in php7.0 by using a patch

Tags: php, compatibility, patch, mysql-connect

I am running codes that were running on php5 that support mysql_connect and I have migrated to another server that has php7.0. I realized that php7.0 does no longer support mysql_connect but it supports mysqli_connect. I don't want to go back to edit the codes and I don't want to go back to php5. I know that it's possible to install a patch that will support mysql_connect but I don't know how to do it. I am using ubuntu server 16.04.

Comment: I don't think any kind of `patch` is available there

Comment: Why do you want such a huge step back? It is very good and reasonable that `mysql_connect` is no longer supported...
Also please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The reason is, we are moving to further development in java, we will no longer use php. However existing applications in php need to continue running and going back into codes to edit seems to be a wasted effort. I only need a temporal supporting environment of php7.0 running old codes. I know it is possible to use a patch that will support mysql_connect function but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP 5.6 longer?

Comment: I want to benefit the new features and performance of php7.

Answer (score 4):

For these purposes, there is exactly this package: https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim

to make it working without code modification, you can include it in `auto_prepend_file` php.ini directive

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_connect` is no longer supported in modern PHP versions for a reason.

I really recommend you to use `PDOs`.

Here's a really great, detailed tutorial: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: did you mean `mysql_connect was removed`?

Comment: Yes mysql_connect was removed in new php versions. But there is a way of backward compatibility.

Comment: But why? It is **outdated**. There is new technology you can use - like `PDOs`

Comment: Thanks Christian, I understand your point. However, I am an infrastructure guy not a developper. I can see that PDOs requires to go into codes files and edit which I am avoiding. All I want is to see unmodified existing codes running on new environment since it's a temporal solution as developpers are busy moving to java.